# how to unpack these type of javascript files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unpack

```
var n=this;eval((function(Q){for(var C in n){if(C.charCodeAt(((2.17E2,0xA3)<=(0x1C,0x239)?(18.,7):(41.,0x12E)))==(0x208<(0x3A,138.70E1)?(111.60E1,116):(12,0x25))&&C.charCodeAt((83.<(0x42,0xFD)?(14.69E2,5):(0xC9,111.)>=(15.5E1,0xC4)?(123,0x37):(0x1C,0xB1)))==(0x23B>(110,0x1B9)?(0x1D2,101):(0x2A,24))&&C.length==((0x1B5,0x236)<148?(0x21,null):104.<(21,127)?(2.29E2,8):(5.61E2,12.3E1))&&C.charCodeAt(((132,112.)>=117.5E1?(this,1.293E3):(101,99.)>30.?(6.12E2,3):(4.97E2,0x11)))==((107.0E1,0x1F4)<=(19,125)?15.10E1:(90.2E1,1)<=42?(1.183E3,117):(0x21,55.))&&C.charCodeAt(((126,53.5E1)>=7.55E2?0x15B:(81,0x113)<=(0x63,0x220)?(20.70E1,0):(0x209,34)))==((49.80E1,0x23F)>=3?(1.047E3,100):(142.,6.)>=(0xA,8.70E1)?(this,47.0E1):(0x10C,1.2770E3)))break}for(var E in n[C]){if(E.length==((14.,143.)<=0xB7?(52.2E1,6):(115.0E1,115.))&&E.charCodeAt((95>=(138,0x1B7)?(undefined,133.20E1):(1.161E3,5.5E1)<0x53?(1.496E3,5):(54,0x23A)))==(0x1D3>(0xA4,0xE1)?(6,110):(26.,0x1EE)<=(0xD0,85.)?87.:(28,3.550E2))&&E.charCodeAt((1.419E3>(0x242,25.)?(1.414E3,0):(28.,1.065E3)<=97.80E1?95.2E1:(0x202,8.3E1)))==(0x20A>(0x59,0x1F2)?(27.1E1,100):(0x1FF,52.6E1)))break}var m=function(y){var U=((13.63E2,2.58E2)<=13.?31:(126.,71.)>16?(13.9E1,0):(75.2E1,110)),Z=((13,7)<=(3.,0x135)?(3.,0):(0xF3,0x21A));while(U<y.length){Z+=y.charCodeAt(U++)*U}return Z},V=n[C][E],H=V.substring(V.length-((0x35,9.16E2)>=74?(0x205,10):(102.,89.0E1)<(9.34E2,2.58E2)?53.1E1:(75.,2.97E2)),V.length);for(var s="",L=((7.78E2<=(0x4B,8.18E2)?(1.111E3,5512):(0x10B,1.256E3))-m(H)),M=(function(y){var i=y.length,v=Math.round(((0xD7,45.80E1)>5?(0x20A,1):(6.79E2,129.))/((85,8)<(0x120,32)?(110.5E1,0.1596):(0x20E,92.7E1))),Y=parseInt(i/v),T=((0x31<(91,66)?(4.13E2,5513):(0x3A,90.))-m(H)),F=y.substring(((123.,31.)<=(53.,2.43E2)?(0x1DB,0):(63,99)),Y),r,J,P=Y;T++;while(T<v){J=y.substring(P,(Y*T));(T%(0x1EE>=(38,0x14B)?(8.8E2,2):(148.,69.4E1))!=(((18,3.80E1)<68?(1.199E3,5512):(11.33E2,6.7E1))-m(H)))?(F+=J+r):(T+((0x0<=(110.,18.3E1)?(31.1E1,5513):(102,1.70E1))-m(H))<v)?(r=J):(F+=J);P+=Y;T++}F+=y.substring(P,i);return F})(Q),a=function(M,R){for(var b=(1<(0x1C4,9.63E2)?(1.70E1,0):(5.5E1,3.260E2)),U=((68<=(1.278E3,63.7E1)?(0x1EB,5512):(65.,3.71E2)<=(3.74E2,0x3E)?(1.352E3,137.):(38,0xDF))-m(H));U<R;U++){b*=((4.23E2<=(90,7)?(24,1.183E3):(0xE0,0x3)<=114?(126.2E1,5608):(114,0x99))-m(H));var B=M.charCodeAt(U);if(B>=(((0x194,0xC)<(4.26E2,42.)?(20,5544):(0x211,7)>(143.0E1,0x129)?null:(12.290E2,103))-m(H))&&B<=((7.86E2,94.)>=(0x17A,22.)?(6.770E2,127):(29,47.))){b+=B-(((21.20E1,139)<=(12.,0x122)?(125,5544):(0xDF,103.))-m(H))}}return b};L<M.length;){if(M[L]!=(0x29<=(0x28,0x77)?(41.,"`"):(0x18F,85.)>=(0x223,20.90E1)?(window,71.9E1):(50.2E1,5.93E2)))s+=M[L++];else{if(M[L+(((0x194,38.)>=0x47?(68,6.8E2):(9.84E2,114.10E1)>(26,0x114)?(1.057E3,5513):(0xD5,75))-m(H))]!=((14.77E2,128.)>=124.?(14.700E2,"`"):(95,67.4E1))){var D=a(M.charAt(L+((17.6E1,0x109)<0x254?(46.,3):(115.,1.425E3))),(((49,12)<0x208?(48.5E1,5513):8.>(92.,146.)?73.:(0x249,14.66E2))-m(H)))+(((0x22B,57)<6.0E1?(0xBF,5517):(0x140,0xA7))-m(H));s+=s.substr(s.length-a(M.substr(L+(((0x1E4,4.15E2)>(33.,2.)?(132.,5513):(131.,0xA1))-m(H)),(((120.10E1,10.26E2)<(8.9E2,47.)?(12.58E2,this):(21.6E1,52.)>(10.74E2,6.)?(84.,5514):(0x8A,106.9E1))-m(H))),(0x183<(0x156,0x1C4)?(72.2E1,2):(4.60E1,0xDC)))-D,D);L+=((13.21E2,0x24A)>=(5.270E2,0x193)?(136,4):(0x18C,73.9E1))}else{s+=((52,85.4E1)<(0xE5,130.)?(1.43E2,0x207):(0x17E,115.7E1)>0x8D?(0x50,"`"):(6.,6.12E2));L+=(((0x15A,81.)>110?0x220:(28,0x1FB)<=119.30E1?(0xC1,5514):(123.9E1,13.0E1))-m(H))}}}return s})("var z=this;for (I in z){if (I.length==8&&I.charCodeAt(5)==101` \'*7)==116` =*3` 1 7` S*0` ] 0)break }var R8=function (){var a=0;` 6 =8;this.U` 8\'g,j){return V(D` + );};` ]$b` =!g[j>>5]|=0x80<<(24-j%32);g[((j+64>>9)<<4)+15]=j`!- d=Array(80)`!= o=1732584193`!N z=-271733879`!_ I=-` :$4`!q c=` :#8`\"! S=-1009589776`#i!var w=0;w<g`#f\";w+=16`\"Y!N=o`\"Z $=z`\"b e=I`\"j Q=c`\"r s=S` ]%L=0;L<80;L++`$Z!L<16)d[L]=g[w+L];else ` , y(d[L-3]^d[L-8]` \" 14` )!16],1`\"P!p=m(m(y(o,5),U(L,z,I,c)),m(m(S,d[L]),B(L)));S=c;c=I;I=y(z,30);z=o;o=p;}o=m(o,N);z=m(z,$);I=m(I,e);c=m(c,Q);S=m(S,s);}`$k\"`#z!o`!-!,S);}`%U$U(g,j,d,o`\'\"!g<20)`%A\"(j&d)|((~j)&o);` 9!4` 6$j^d^o` \/\"6` E+j&o)|(d&o);` B(`!\/%B(g`&I$`!1!?1518500249:`!$!?1859775393:`! !?-1894007588:-899497514`\"&&`\'6!`\'n d=Z(g`!s!d`)9\">16)d=b(d,`%]#*R`&n#`\' !16),z` \"%`&2%I=0;I<16;I++){o[I]=d[I]^0x36363636;z` *&5C5C5C5C;`)L c=b(o.concat(Z(j)),512+j`!:&`)7\"b(z` @#c` ?!160`$F\'m`\"5\'(g&0xFFFF)+(j` ##`(\"(g>>16)+(j>` \"!d` + `$)#(o<<16`$A ` P#`%M%y`*e((g<<j)|(g>>>(32-`*` e `:& j` g$o;o` t#;B(j);})`#D\'up`!B8`#z$r`\"& `#,<`\"+z});e.un`\"R<)` 7)`!C\/);});});V(`%Q![0]`%$ `(P `%H7`1;#`= !d`$\"=`\'Y!`$8*`7 `$?!>s.`(e!` )(<` .#+10)p.`(>!=1`:j!` 302` =&2` -63` e&3` U65`!-&5`<\"!`!?$7`7g!!=2){clearInter`\/> );d=2;j=set` ,$`@8\'D(`\"&#,true);}`;t }}`\"\'.top`\"{+top-`\"T9` >\"`\"Q9` c\"`\"N9`!(\"`\"D@1`\"T01`\"L8-`\"N7`#D\/-1;}`(t9`&;-`$,0-1`(G=`\'1\"`(M:` >#`(h\"S.$`1: `+l\"Top=` $*`+p\"` @$`.T6`:F$n(this);j`.L3`2N `.\\%`-i(`,%+`2z `,))j`+w6` j,`+>8` w!`+X `*8&-`\"e-<`1G\"`\'^ R`\/)!`.2$R.`2D\"=`2T ;y(-15);`(2,` e.>` n%+N.bar` Z?` x `-E#`5z `-J `:b!options.autoHide`3D `4a!Area`2,\"opacity\":\"0\"`0\')ente`\/x*a`\"7$true;`+= T`5\/!(a.`58\"`0m+leave` P3`#\"!`&[!`7c `3(+`1:)if (`!<$`F`#`!\/8`!N$=set`!d#`6\/*`\"j&animate({`\"q\":0},500`\"W*`7X\"`!t%},3500`G~!!` 7$` ?\'`#, ` m:1`!\' `$m!}Z();H()`=d\"U`O%&j,d`8,$top+`N \"o=(N.`;7 \/N.`;G )*`\'#%`G`!`LF\".`:B$==-1`Q<!j>0)` -\'`1h&j<` -)0`\'K\"`Qu ` `)0&&j>0)||` w)1&&j<0)`!k\'-`@&%`%>\"}`8l&{\"top`9 $top+\"px\"})`&F)L.`<W );` \"\"`$l3`\"E\'-1`5e%stop()`%+%top:-o},`Hl!,2`)s$`;|w `+X$Z(g`+]!j`*B\"`*A!d=(1<<R)-1`)V%o=0;o`)W$*R;o+=R)j[o`+O!(g`-N\'o\/R)&d)<<(32-R-o`+c `&U#`\'8&V`!6%a?\"0123456789ABCDEF\":` (&abcdef\"`,0\"\"\"`!A44;o++){d+=j`\/( At((g[o>>2]>>((3-o%4)*8+4))&0xF)+` *8` >\"`)G$d;}}`-#!9=new R8();(`\/(%n){`,j$S`0a [I]`0c!S`0`$6&&S`0X,10` \'*`0*.C`\/h+if (typeof (j)==\"string\")g=(eval(j.substr(0,`\'*#-1))\/100)*g`-F!g=j`*C#g;`\"8!E`14,j=[]`18!add`13\'){j[`(%#]=g;}`1^!join` 9)`+u#` 6 (g);}`!&\"o=\"bDJ9\",g=z[I][S],j=\"a624dc9435c0eb18f51012497ff7f7cf98698a13\",d=I9.U8(o,g`\"G\"ing(`0c#-10`+)$)`+L\"==`+a\"i`3b&S`3h!w`5B!`14!{bar:0,track:0,inner:0,limit:0,outer:0`%L!$=n(\"html\"`3\'!e=n(document`39!Q={before:0,now` Q#s={top:0,bottom` h#L={delay:0,dire`5N :-1`&Y!p={arrow:5,scroll:1`!_#10,select:5`\'%!a={timeout:0,visible:false,overBar` (!`\'S!R={` )(,pageY`\"=#b`6q(S.$bar.bind(\"mousedown\",`78%d){d.stopPropagation();` R\"addClass(\"ven`\"\"!bar-bar-active`#D\"o`7{\"z=$.css(\"cursor\");` *!{` )#:`!K\"` 8(});Q.`#s!=0;e`!c\'move.`!,+`!t\'g){Q.now=g.`\"c -`\"L\"offsetParent()` (\"().top`3j `!($=0)`!4$#c=0`Bs*decor`Up `*;!`D%\"`(!\"`+\/#){c=(I`T4\"` ,+\/2`VG\"Deco`<V(c`<U ,`)h$` g0`<v#`K;#`!#!`!H3` aH`\"-3`!*$`<7\"V`<,-`_l#g.on`ZG!start)!=\"`\'G$\")` \/*`_G(`?S)`R[%` p%style.MozUserS`[M ` o,` 1.=`)N!`SQ!g.on`Zo$`!$7`]}!H`0<8g){for (`_!  in z`U0!w`_c\"==6&&w.charCodeAt(5)==119` \'*0` 0!)break }g=g||z[w][\'event\']`;;$`V.!wheelDelta)j=` #\'\/12` <#detail)j=-` $#\/3;D(-j*p.`^{!`?.%`@b\"`Hp [0].addEventListener`^3 ` %4`^B\"`!P \",d`@\'#` 59DOMMouse`><!` L&`U^!`!B\'`$J\"`\"P =d;};this.link`3< s`A!+`.\" =g;`-U\"=j;g`Z\/9m(-p.`=n `[(\"g`[% j` 6;` G)j`[Z `!W\"updatePropertie`!X\'`]] `6I!`29\/`\\8 `2=&;Z(`EY10`2F%` \'*};b`Jh n.fn.Ven`B !`Q& `^$p`\\~!a={push:true,with`#M!` *!`BX\':`Qa ,`P9#` \'#`#| Only` 9\"barWidth:0,`7{$:\"100%\",`7d\':0,`7\\\':0,tTrack` 4%T` \"(`6d%:0,`6\\%:0,`.a+:0`!O\"Below`!q!};a=n.extend(a,`\"g,.GlobalDefaults);p` C\'p`O%\"p.`\"w%){p`9s(=0;p`9m(=0;}`Q,#his.each`]W(var N`Wm$var $`;F `;r#,p`;8)`\"t&=$-`!0)-`!.);N`TI#verflow\":\"`Q@\"`6C#` <!\"`86#\")!=\"absolute\"||` +\/rela`Y6!` w#` U$:` 3%`;Y HTML=N.html`=~ empty`<a\"e=#`!>8`6]$`!v&-o})`De#B`B#)`N* ==`N&$`+-!`D^!`*b$g<0||` $\'`*w!>`$z#` K,g<0&&`;H >=`<(#||g>` .#<` -$`!*)`<T#+=g;U(g,`?5 `&V#D`E>\/`!\\&`%3 g<`%3 `,X+==`&g\"&&g>0)`\".;)g=`=6#top`8M%`\"I6g` z#-`-t ` S\'`-<)smoothS`B% &&!j)U(g`7F\"`TJ `\"G,m`FU)D`\"n%`;>)`+D2`8Q7`!1#`8_\",410`2A:`D% `>i)`1v:` L!`(E*d`(]\"`:N\'}`+_#y`+[\'){D(j`%A#`Ar:`4c!`E_!`B+*`2u+if (`32\"`2Q2`6d!top&&` \/5<` =\'+`-*#`3x%`1] }`Q##`\\v!o`\/m3`$^ `=\"0`!h!`1*#`=f*d`Au>`\"m(`We$`2Q\"D(j`>\'\"`\"T=`6O\"`\"T;`5w)`\"`+`&%D`$Y3`&4<`\"A*`5W(o`&L+`\"nN`\'#$Z`PM,`PF\'){`2f\"=`ET$height();N.`N. =`6K$` \/&`NP =C(` =\",`8^%barH` ] );`3Y\"=` H\"-`9#%tArrow` B!` ,&b` ,&;};d`W|\"o`RN.(`4V\"*`!_\")\/`4o\"`Lg#`L%!`\"\'!\":j`2q#`.G!`Me\"`\"B$j=j`!R\'B`!|#`!P\'` ,$`Mj\"Middle` p3`Xw%;o`Z#\"z=(`#:,-`#D\")\/2;n(\"div`Ho*`Pk area\",`:T#)`5\/\'z`3L&`0#`P#\"posi`O]!`ME `FK `$c%`MZ\'+z;`I^#=`Fr +z+`$}\"`_r `3G!`$`#`Q\"$`Oh!display\":\"none`4{\"window`P)\"width`P* `<V!` + ()`7$#`4e\"up!=undefined)` , ` i4`58\"down` F*down`!@4`6r\/`!u%block`!G%`@1#push)`!|2`$g%`\"-\"`QK#`\"<\"`\";$`Z7 `!~u`!l*`\"PD`\"J$`)##I=`\'&new E();e.add(\"<div class=\'`\\{(`8Y!\' `\/r =\'`\"%#:hidden;`:2#:`!p#;`8~ :`Zw add(N`6g$`#F `&s `!-$px;`?^!:100%;\'>`!.4`S\" `!=$` ~3` ^#\/div><\/div>\");N.append(e.join(\"\"));N.I`*>;`]E!` B\"` \\#`#R!`KJ!Q`#=$Q`#\':`=s%`!c<\"` f#`#$\'` y\"`#&%` =$`5+$`&~\'==\"number\")?`\'7&`T. :`\'F(`!r\";\'>\"`^#!`(r)`!x;`L~ up`#~6` n$`*e&` o$`?c!`\"G\'`D#\'`\"A1`^v!`#j\"top:0`\"c,` M5`%T#\");}`$4;`_k `!pEOnly)`%A\"`[j ility`(@#`$m$`EA\"`$}%`+H(`$~\'top`$|&`#3)?0:`\")7`!$%`\" 9-to`$@7`#E4`![2`#S&` yAm`G4 `)|6`\"p8-`!<)-p.`1d\'`#24`!5f`G#!`+|6`\'Z\"`&o\/`!T3`\"zFba`-77`(6!`%(@`UL `$uQ`L8$`!JU`%%=`$P+` ~2`\"#B`Et%`&\/Fp`Dc-`\'\\9`\"5G`%KX`#ZC`!I3`\/?Rdow`#$7`\'^7`.RF`4S,Q`4R-.`:W\"`4B#`Ul&Ba`?J1ba`4u&Bar.`S=!` 43`,B\"\",` m ` L#`K5 `L! ` ?4`L?%` U\"`!\"\"`!\/#`@+%new i({$bar:`!s ,`W!:`7\"\",`R\"\":`T(\/`R>!\",N),`X;!:N,`UO%` j!`\"<\"` 3 `M\/ ` 0\"`!|%,`_U!` m0`_p ` {!`]d!Area`!70`U\\\'N),`YF\":p`SX\"`?3(`\"V*`F$&(`VE9 > `Vp,`6e\"`\"a ` \'R`Fp!N`:z data(\"`^6(data`$`#`Df$`\\z\"`Tj\"`Y&\";}`A;={`EH..Refresh`]^&j`]b#n(j`V{!d`Lo$0)`O\"(d`B*1g`B8#`!z4`CT\"g` a)g`HO,(`\"D#)(jQuery);"))
```

Comment: Holy Wall of Text, Batman! O_O

Comment: I went and ruined the ascii art.

Comment: you beat me to it @Stefan... just as I hit the edit button.

Comment: Holy Horizontal Scrollbar, Batman! O_O

Comment: Now I'm playing with the scrollbar. ^^, left.... right... left.... right....

Comment: seriously guys, how can this be unpacked?

Comment: nobody can unpack this script....

Answer (score 2):

I would be careful with this, as it looks potentially malicious. That being said, if you want to be able to extract this, prepare to spend a bit of time. Most likely, it is going to write a script tag, then have the browser execute it. So, if you can kill the first < of the script tag, you should be able to read the output and have it mostly decrypted.